# Remove Dev warning from Google Chrome (Linux)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, ubuntu-9.04

I really hate the Google Chrome Dev warning that opens every time I use Google Chrome on Linux. Is there anyway to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options (click the "gear" button on the far right), click the "Basic" tab, and tell it to "Open the home page", and for the Home page, set something like "Use the New Tab Page".

Comment: Thats the way my settings are already set. Are you using Linux?

Comment: Yes, I am. What version of chrome are you running?

Comment: So it turns out Google removed the warning in the future builds.